# How to calculate strike rate of a cricket batsman with fully considering extras?

Tags: cricket

AS title, there are 5 types of extras as I know: byes, no balls, leg byes, penalty, and wides. Is there a way to tell which type of extras needs to be counted and which doesn't?

I'm a totally newbie so if what I list is not accurate, feel free to elaborate on your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all covered in [Law 18.10 "Crediting of runs scored"](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/scoring-runs):

> Unless stated otherwise in any of the Laws,
>
> 18.10.1 if the ball is struck by the bat, all runs scored by the batting side shall be credited to the striker, except for the following:
>
> - an award of 5 Penalty runs, which shall be scored as Penalty runs
> - the one run penalty for a No ball, which shall be scored as a No balls extra.
>
> 18.10.2 if the ball is not struck by the bat, runs shall be scored as Penalty runs, Byes, Leg byes, No ball extras or Wides as the case may be.  If Byes or Leg byes accrue from a No ball, only the one run penalty for No ball shall be scored as such, and the remainder as Byes or Leg byes as appropriate.

Strike rate is then just the number of runs credited to the batsman divided by the number of (valid) balls they faced, traditionally then multiplied by 100.

Comment: So can you elaborate on what valid balls are?

Comment: Anything that counts as one of the over - i.e. not a no ball or wide.

Comment: Ok, and should I subtract the runs credited from extras including byes/legbyes/penalties?

Comment: Subtract from what? The runs listed for the batter on the scoresheet are the runs you care about, extras are listed separately.

Comment: @MemphisMeng Legal deliveries are balls that are not wides or no balls.